# Reading the files from a log file list

Tags: python, file-io

I have the following log file called `log.txt`, with all the file names to be considered from a folder:

```
log.txt 
C:\data\01.log 
C:\data\02.log 
C:\data\03.log 
C:\data\04.log
```

My task is to read these files one after another from log.txt using a for loop.

```
with open("C:\data\log.txt",'r') as f: 
    logs=f.read() 
    print logs 
for line in logs: 
       line = myfile.readline().replace('\n', '') 
       with open(line, 'r') as myfile: 
        lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in myfile.readlines()]
```

I am getting this error:

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Comment: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python

Comment: Please try to create some example code (given the link by Kartik), and come back with that code if it does not work as expected.

Comment: Thank you Kartik, Alex

I have the following code to read the "log.txt"

with open("C:\data\log.txt",'r') as f:
    logs=f.read()
    print logs

C:\data\01.log
C:\data\02.log
C:\data\03.log
C:\data\04.log

I am trying to open each log file :
for line in logs:
#jstring = myfile.readline().replace('\n', '')
        with open(line, 'r') as myfile:
              lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in myfile.readlines()]

I am getting the error as "IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:"

Comment: @Kali, update your question with the code. Do not use a comment for that. Thanks. (There will be a link saying "edit" under the question, under the tags, python and file-io. Click that and paste your code. Take a minute to familiarize yourself with the formatting options at the top of the edit box. Properly format your code to look good in the preview below the edit box, then click save changes. We will appreciate you efforts.)

Comment: Sure Kartik.. Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you are getting?

Is it "IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:"?

This error means that the directory C:\data\ does not exist. Are you sure this folder exists? Also if it does exist, is the logs.txt file in that directory?

I personally do not have a C:\data directory, so unless you created it, you have the address of the wrong directory.

Comment: Yes.. the path C:\data\  does exist. I have manually created a folder 'data' in  C drive. Thank you